# Grounding Li-ion battery pack to stop amplifier hum

Tags: inverter, guitar-amplifier, hum

I'm trying to connect a tube guitar amplifier to the Delta 1300 W battery pack by Echo Flo. The pack is not grounded, so I get a hum.

Echo Flo suggested connecting the amp to a power strip, then plugging that into one of the 120 V outlets on the pack. This reduced the hum, but it is still way too distracting.

I tried connecting a ground wire to the ground prong on the power strip and sticking the other end in the ground.
I also tried holding the end of the ground wire to see if I could act as ground, to no avail.
Because of this hum I don’t think any musicians can play in remote locations without a hum.

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a block diagram of what you have and how it’s connected.

Comment: Does it work without hum when connected to the mains?

Comment: Have you measured the frequency of the hum? This may give you a hint at the source. If you are isolated from residential line voltage there should not be any line frequency noise, unless you happen to have unsheilded cables laying near a line voltage source.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to your problem?
I have exactly the same problem when power any amp with a Goal Zero Yeti 1500 watt battery pack... so anyoning... bought it specifically to play outside where no power is available, and it is unsusable... Thanks for sharing if you have a solution.
Take care,
Eric

Comment: The only thing that helped was connecting a power strip to the battery and plugging the amp into that. Still a hum but a whole lot less. I recently bought a little Donner Noise Killer stomp box -$35 (very well built). I think it works but there was a lot of beer and weed while I played and I'm not really sure if it worked. I think it did. I'll be trying it again tonight before lively up time.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of grounding is almost surely not the main issue here.  What you have isn't just a battery pack...it's also an inverter...it creates 120V AC from a DC battery.  The problem is, this AC is gonna likely not look like a true sine wave.  Instead of a smoothly varying sinusoidal curve, the output from an inverter will be anything but. Likely a series of voltage levels that would look like a staircase going up then down.  This is because it's way cheaper and easier to create such rather than a smooth sine wave.

For most appliances this is irrelevant.  But not for your amp or really any other analog audio gear.  These non-sinusoidal artifacts create harmonics that are able to bleed past your amps filters because they're not meant to deal with it.  The perturbations end up on the amps internal DC rails and you hear it.

How to fix?  Well one option is to massively increase the filtering. That could be a expensive trial and error thing.  Another option is get a better battery pack, one which explicitly advertises and brags about how clean and sinusoidal its output is.   If it were me, I'd try a 1:1 isolation transformer.  Not to achieve isolation, but rather because a transformer is a big inductor and it'll help filter out that hash.  But they're not cheap...I happen to have access to them so I'd be able to try for free...you'd have to procure one, probably about $100 and would be heavy.

You could also try a power line conditioner like a Furhman, but I don't think it'd be enough (you maybe have a friend with one would let you try it)

My real suggestion is forget the tube amp and get a modeling amp that has a switching power supply and thus will be in a better position to reject the line noise.  You'd have to check the schematics and see the nature of the supply but I think most modelers would have this kind of supply.  I know I know...blasphemy  lol.  I like my tube amps too.  :)